# C++ primer 5 th ed. matching flag type

Tags: c++, regex

I have this exercise from C++ primer 5th ed.

> Exercise 17.26: Rewrite your phone program so that it writes only the second and subsequent phone numbers for people with more than one phone number.

my solution for the previous exercise: A program for finding the first match and format it using the formatting string `fmt` and output only the first number:

```
int main(){

    std::string pattern = "(\\()?(\\d{3})(\\))?([-. ])?(\\d{3})([-. ])?(\\d{4})";
    std::regex reg(pattern);
    std::string fmt = "$2.$5.$7 ";

    for(std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
        std::cout << std::regex_replace(line, reg, fmt, format_first_only | format_no_copy) << '\n';

}
```

Input:

```
 morgan (201) 555-2368 862-555-0123
 drew (973)555.0130
 lee (609) 555-0132 2015550175 800.555-0000
```

Output:

```
201.555.2368
973.555.0130
609.555.0132
```

- AS you can see it formats the first match only and outputs it. So How can I format and output all the matches but the first? I find it a bit difficult to achieve since there's no Matching Flag Type as format_second...?

Comment: use `regex_search`

Comment: Why voting down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tricky: you need to get rid off the first match then apply the matching flag: `std::regex_constants::format_no_copy`into `std::regex_replace`:

- `std::sregex_iterator` is your choice because it can be initialized to denote the first match then we use its member: `suffix().str()` passing it to `std::regex_replace`:

  ```
    int main(){

        std::string pattern = "(\\()?(\\d{3})(\\))?([-. ])?(\\d{3})([-. ])?(\\d{4})";
        std::regex reg(pattern);
        std::string fmt = "$2.$5.$7 ";

        for(std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ){
            // it points to the first match (phone number)
            std::sregex_iterator it(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), reg);
            // we use suffix as the input sequence skipping the first match
            std::cout << std::regex_replace(it->suffix().str(), reg, fmt, format_no_copy) << '\n';
        }
    }
  ```

Input:

```
 morgan (201) 555-2368 862-555-0123
 drew (973)555.0130
 lee (609) 555-0132 2015550175 800.555-0000
```

Output:

```
862.555.0123

201.555.0175 800.555.0000
```